Cannot set pull down on RPI4 using overlay
As my device is using interrupt pin (active high), I'm trying to set pull down resistor on the interrupt pin (GPIO4), however for some reason it does not work. Here is my devicetree overlay:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>
#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/bcm2835.h>


&i2c1 {
    mydev: mydev@1a {
        compatible = "mydev";
        reg = <0x1a>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
        interrupts = <4 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING>;
        pinctrl-name = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&mydev_pins>;
    };
};

&gpio {
    mydev_pins: mydev_pins {
        brcm,pins = <4>;
        brcm,function = <BCM2835_FSEL_GPIO_IN>;
        bias-pull-down; // Does not work
        brcm,pull = <1>; // Legacy option also does not work
    };
};

The overlay is enabled in /boot/config it's loaded properly as the appropriate kernel driver gets loaded, however pinctrl config does not change anything.
Whatever option I use raspi-gpi shows


GPIO 4: level=1 func=INPUT pull=UP


all the time
What else can I check?

What's with the first stanza (&i2c1)??  I2C lines have PULL-UPs by default.
